# How to collect data from multiple child components at once in angular?

Tags: angular

I have multiple same components in my parent component and I want to collect data from all of them at once. I just generate new components when I hit a "add new form" button. I need to generate multiple same components that are just forms but completed with different data.

This is the parent component:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of studyFormsNmb">
  <app-study-form></app-study-form>
</div>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="increaseStudyForm(1)">Add studies</button>
```

and his typescript file

```
studyFormsNmb = Array(1);

  increaseStudyForm(i) {
    this.studyFormsNmb.push(i);
  }
```

This is the child component html :

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="studyFormGroup" class="studyForm">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Study place</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Study place"
        formControlName="placeCtrl"
        required
      />
      <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Period</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Period"
        formControlName="periodCtrl"
        required
      />
      <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Study level</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Study level"
        formControlName="levelCtrl"
        required
      />
      <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Degree</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Degree"
        formControlName="degreeCtrl"
        required
      />
      <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</div>
```

and his typescript file:

```
studyFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createFormControl();
  }

  createFormControl() {
    this.studyFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      placeCtrl: ["", Validators.required],
      periodCtrl: ["", Validators.required],
      levelCtrl: ["", Validators.required],
      degreeCtrl: ["", Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

So I need the data from all these forms, as an individual object for each form, to add in a list of objects. I searched and thought about @Input and @Output but something doesn't add up, I don't know how to get individual data from each component, if so do I need an ID for each component?

Comment: I run your app in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/), fist I see you don't have submit.

Comment: @Hamada Oh you are right so I really need a button on every form to submit the data?

Comment: I add an answer with code and a demo with this aproche.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can help you

Parent Compnonent

```
<div *ngFor="let i of studyFormsNmb">
  <dialog-content-example-dialog (newItemEvent)="receiveForm($event)"></dialog-content-example-dialog>
</div>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="increaseStudyForm(1)">Add studies</button>

The test will show all forms {} in the array

Message: {{arrForms | json}}
```

Child Component

```
<div>
  <form [formGroup]="studyFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="studyForm" >
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Study place</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Study place"
        formControlName="placeCtrl"
        required
      />
      <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Period</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Period"
        formControlName="periodCtrl"
        required
      />
      <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Study level</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Study level"
        formControlName="levelCtrl"
        required
      />
      <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Degree</mat-label>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="Degree"
        formControlName="degreeCtrl"
        required
      />
      <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>

    <button class="button" type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Ts file's

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-content-example',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-content-example.html',
})
export class DialogContentExample {
  arrForms: Array<{}> = [];
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  studyFormsNmb = Array(1);

  increaseStudyForm(i: any) {
    this.studyFormsNmb.push(i);
  }

 form: {};
receiveForm($event: {}){
  this.form = $event
  this.arrForms.push($event);
}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-content-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-content-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogContentExampleDialog {

@Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();


studyFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createFormControl();
  }

  createFormControl() {
    this.studyFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      placeCtrl: ["", Validators.required],
      periodCtrl: ["", Validators.required],
      levelCtrl: ["", Validators.required],
      degreeCtrl: ["", Validators.required],
    });
  }
  

  onSubmit() {
    this.newItemEvent.emit(this.studyFormGroup.value);
  }

}
```

Here is the demo [app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m8rqq3?file=src/app/dialog-content-example-dialog.html)

Comment: Thanks , I did that too , but I only was wondering if I can collect all the data without needing to press a submit button on every form

Comment: In the Parent or Child, you can use `ngOnInit() {onChanges(): void {
  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    this.formText = for (item in val} ...}` And get changes  if you like.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of this !